# Как записать смайлы в MySQL? Или вырезать их из текста?

Tags: mysql, python

Добрый вечер.
Никак не могу записать в базу сообщения/комменты из VK, которые содержат смайлы.
Записываю через python+mysqldb+peewee. Изменил кодировку MySQL на `utf8mb4`

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;

ALTER DATABASE first_db CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE first_db.vkpost CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE first_db.vkcomment CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE first_db.vkpost CHANGE content content longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE first_db.vkcomment CHANGE content content longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

Однако, что бы я не делал, на выходе всегда одно и то же.
`(1366, u"Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x8A \\xD0...' for column 'content' at row 1")`

Если вносить данные вручную, то MySQL Workbench выдает эту же самую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно ее победить или вообще вырезать смайлы из текста?
Вырезать смайлы, наверно, даже лучше, чтобы лишнее не хранить.

Comment: Каким конкретно запросом записываете-то? Правильную кодировку в mysqldb выставили? Передаёте именно юникод, а не байтовую строку? Короче, Python-код в студию

Comment: А вырезать смайлы не надо, будут лучи ненависти от пользователей в лице меня)

Comment: Питон не при чем, попробовал без него и получил эту же ошибку

Comment: А в MySQL Workbench возможно просто баг, давайте именно Python-код, у меня смайлики всегда прекрасно записывались

Comment: Забыл кодировку в подключении указать `db = MySQLDatabase('first_db', host='0.0.0.0', port=3306, user='user', password='1233', charset='utf8mb4')` :)

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге MySQL (например, в `/etc/mysql/conf.d/unicode.cnf`) в релевантной секции указать:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server    = utf8mb4
collation-server        = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Перезапустить MySQL и проверить:

```
mysql --silent --raw <<DOC | column -t 
show variables like 'character\_set\_%'; 
show variables like 'collation%'; 
DOC
```

Должно вывести что-то такое:

```
character_set_client      utf8mb4
character_set_connection  utf8mb4
character_set_database    utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem  binary
character_set_results     utf8mb4
character_set_server      utf8mb4
character_set_system      utf8
collation_connection      utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database        utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server          utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно при внесении смайлов в базу задавать их внутренним кодом, а при выводе из базы текста - прогонять его через обратную функцию. Так можно гарантированно обеспечить сохранение данных по смайлам (что особенно актуально при переносе/импорте базы, когда из-за неправильной кодировки могут быть вырезаны некоторые спецсимволы) и использовать смайлы не входящие в стандартный Юникод.